# Select a JSON array based on name value and change the array into a Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to select a particular JSON array (that corresponds to the name "contents" below) and change this array into a pandas dataframe? My json is as follows

```
html_sample3 =    """{
         "orderID": 12345,
          "shopperName": "John Smith",
          "shopperEmail": "johnsmith@example.com",
          "contents": [
            {
              "productID": 34,
              "productName": "SuperWidget",
              "quantity": 1
            },
            {
              "productID": 56,
              "productName": "WonderWidget",
              "quantity": 3
            }
          ],
          "orderCompleted": true
        }"""
```

Code I have written is pretty sparse as stumped on this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_sample3)
```

The dataframe I would like looks as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on provided information, you could transform your string with `json.loads()` and use `pandas.json_normalize()`:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_sample =    json.loads("""{
         "orderID": 12345,
          "shopperName": "John Smith",
          "shopperEmail": "johnsmith@example.com",
          "contents": [
            {
              "productID": 34,
              "productName": "SuperWidget",
              "quantity": 1
            },
            {
              "productID": 56,
              "productName": "WonderWidget",
              "quantity": 3
            }
          ],
          "orderCompleted": true
        }""")


pd.json_normalize(json_sample, record_path='contents')
```

##### Output

|  | productID | productName | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 34 | SuperWidget | 1 |
| 1 | 56 | WonderWidget | 3 |